# Converting Django Templates to Jinja Templates - Automatically Scope

Tags: django, templates, jinja2

I am going through the not-very-fun process of converting my Django templates into Jinja templates. One big headache I've run into is that in Jinja, variables in scope in a parent block do not automatically trickle down into a child block. For example, the following will not work:

```
{% for item in seq %}
    <li>{% block loop_item %}{{ item }}{% endblock %}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

I understand that this problem can be fixed by adding the `scoped` keyword in the `block` tag.  However, I have many different blocks in my templates and adding the `scoped` keyword will be quite painful.  Is there some way to automatically have the scope apply to child blocks? A type of auto-scoping or something?

Eventually I will convert everything to the Jinja-preferred way, but this would make the conversion process a bit smoother.